# How do you pick a random item in sqlite and flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I have created a flutter app using [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) .
the data stored in the database is displayed using itemBuilder like below code

```
....
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => GestureDetector(
       onTap: () {},
       child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         child: Container(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
           child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Expanded(
                     child: Padding(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                       child: Text(
                         clientList[index].numberphone,
                         style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
               Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                 child: Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                   children: <Widget>[
                     Expanded(
                       child: Text(clientList[index].price.toString() ?? 0,
                           style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
                     )
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
```

Now I want to select a list of customers from clientList that meet some conditions, such as the price of customer being greater than 1000.
Then, when click on the outlined button  choose a random item from this list.

Any idea or code  to do that?

Answer (score 0):

By "randomly selects an item from the list that meets some conditions" I take it you're referring to `clientList`?

Your question breaks down into two parts:

1. **List items that meet some conditions.** For this part, you can use [Iterable.where()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html).
2. **Selecting a random item.** For this, use [Iterable.sample()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/sample.html) from the [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection).

Here's an example of how it might look:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

var itemsThatMeetCriteria = clientList.where((customer) => customer.price > 1000);
var randomItem = itemsThatMeetCriteria.sample(1).single;
```

Comment: Yes, I want to select a list of customers from clientList that meet some conditions, such as the price of customer being greater than 1000.
 Then, when click on the outlined button  choose a random item from this list.

Comment: If that answer works for you, then please accept it

Comment: @JakhongirAnasov iget the error: The method 'sample' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable'.

Comment: He said from library. You need collection package which you find from pub.dev . It would be good if question askers read answers carefully